# How to transform rows into column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS SQL Server and I have below table:

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| SrNo      |    ApprCode      |  ApprName        |     ApprStatus      |      ApprDate           |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| SR_176    |   X001           |   James          |   APR               | 2019-10-03              |
| SR_176    |   X002           |   Sam            |   APR               | 2019-10-03              |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

Tried with PIVOT but its showing `james` and `X001` as a column heading:

**Expected Result:**

```
+-----------+-------------- +---------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
    SrNo    | ApprCode_1    | ApprName_1    | ApprDate_2               ApprCode_2     ApprName_2     ApprDate_2  
+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
    SR_176     X001             James         2019-10-03               X002           Sam            2019-10-03
+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+---- ---------------------+------------------+
```

Query to generate data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    SrNo NVARCHAR(200),
    ApprCode NVARCHAR(200),
    ApprName NVARCHAR(200),
    ApprDate Date
)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('SR_176','X001','James', '2019-10-03')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES ('SR_176','X002','Sam', '2019-10-03')
```

Query that I tried:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @name_concat nvarchar(max)
declare @name1_concat nvarchar(max)
declare @select_aggs nvarchar(max)
select @name_concat = STUFF((select distinct ',' + quotename(ApprCode) from #Temp order by 1 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
select @name1_concat = STUFF((select distinct ',' + quotename(ApprName) from #Temp order by 1 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @sql = '
;with cte2 as
(
    SELECT SrNo,' + @name_concat + ',' + @name1_concat + '
    FROM #Temp
    PIVOT(MAX(ApprCode)
          FOR ApprCode IN (' + @name_concat + ')) AS PVTTable PIVOT
          (
          MAX(ApprName)
          FOR ApprName IN (' + @name1_concat + ')) AS PVTTable1
)
select * from cte2
'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Looks like you need `ROW_NUMBER`, I would also suggest using a Cross-tab, rather than `PIVOT`.

Comment: @Larnu `Cross-tab`? Can you provide one sample demo?

Comment: [Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 1 – Converting Rows to Columns](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-%E2%80%93-converting-rows-to-columns-1)

Comment: @Larnu How I can set `CASE WHEN rn= 1 THEN ApproverName as [1stAppr] ELSE as [2ndAppr]`?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks a lot! You can guide me to optimize or anything that needs to be done for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`Case Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

Here is the query:

```
 SELECT *,
       Row_number()
         OVER(
           partition BY srno
           ORDER BY apprdate) AS RN
INTO   #temptable
FROM   #temp

SELECT srno,
       CASE rn
         WHEN 1 THEN Max(apprname)
       END AS [1 Approver],
       CASE rn
         WHEN 2 THEN Max(apprname)
       END AS [2 Approver],
       CASE rn
         WHEN 1 THEN Max(apprcode)
       END AS [1 ApproverCode],
       CASE rn
         WHEN 2 THEN Max(apprcode)
       END AS [2 ApproverCode],
       CASE rn
         WHEN 1 THEN Max(apprdate)
       END AS [1 Date],
       CASE rn
         WHEN 2 THEN Max(apprdate)
       END AS [2 Date]
INTO   #james
FROM   #temptable
GROUP  BY srno,
          rn

SELECT srno,
       Max([1 approver])     AS ApproverName_1,
       Max([1 approvercode]) AS ApproverCode_1,
       Max([1 date])         AS ApproverDate_1,
       Max([2 approver])     AS ApproverName_2,
       Max([2 approvercode]) AS ApproverCode_2,
       Max([2 date])         AS ApproverDate_2
FROM   #james
GROUP  BY srno
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, This is not a `SQL Pivot` situation and the sample data for question is not enough to test it completely but you can find the main idea :

```
Select
    SrNo,
    MAX(IIF(ApprCode = 'X001', ApprCode, null)) as ApprCode_1,
    MAX(IIF(ApprCode = 'X001', ApprName, null)) as ApprName_1,
    MAX(IIF(ApprCode = 'X001', ApprDate, null)) as ApprDate_1,
    MAX(IIF(ApprCode = 'X002', ApprCode, null)) as ApprCode_2,
    MAX(IIF(ApprCode = 'X002', ApprName, null)) as ApprName_2,
    MAX(IIF(ApprCode = 'X002', ApprDate, null)) as ApprDate_2
From #Temp
Group by SrNo
```

This code works if `ApprCode` was the key to make two separate columns & `SrNo` is for the group by between rows.

Comment: As you can see there can be any user comes as a approver so based in approver code it will not work